# Add Qlabels in PyQt5 on runtime

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to add **Qlabels** on **runtime** by clicking the **pushbutton**.

For example, I want to add **"Helloworld"** text label each time the button is clicked.

I have written code but it replaces not add **Qlabel** in scrollArea, I want to add "Helloworld" in the scrollArea each time the pushbutton is pressed. Secondly, I have created the Qlabel label_99 on runtime, But I think this will not work. As
multiple Qlabels must be created on runtime, as I want to add Qlabel each time I click a pushbutton.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 80, 221, 301))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 219, 299))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 110, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def button_pressed(self):
        print("button pressed")
        self.add_new_label()
    def add_new_label(self):
        self.label_99 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_99=QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_99.setText("HelloWorld")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(label_99)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setWidget` sets the widget for the scroll are, and that is why the code you have doesn't work since it removes the previous widget from the scroll area, and sets the new label as the scroll area widget.

You need to create a new instance of `QLabel`, and add it to the layout of the scroll area widget, which is `self.verticalLayout` for the above class.

```py
    def add_new_label(self):
        newLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(newLabel)
```

The code to create new label and assign it class instance attribute as `self.label_99 = QtWidgets.QLabel()` is useless in your case. You just need to create a local variable to hold the label, and finally add it to the scroll area's widget's layout.